# Hide a image only from homepage

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to hide a logo from footer, only in homepage all other pages it should be shown. I cant figure out a solution as a beginner in react please help.

Comment: Can you edit the question and [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it. Please note that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gatsby exposes a [location property](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/location-data-from-props/) by default in top-level components (pages and templates) so in your homepage (`index.js`) you only need to do something like:

```
const IndexPage = (props) => (
  <Layout>
    <Seo title="Home" />
    {props.location.pathname !== "/" && (
      <StaticImage
        src="../images/example.png"
        loading="eager"
        width={64}
        quality={95}
        formats={["auto", "webp", "avif"]}
        alt=""
        style={{ marginBottom: `var(--space-3)` }}
      />
    )}
  </Layout>
);
```

In the example above, I'm assuming the image you want to hide is a `StaticImage` but you can replace it with your image or whatever you want.

The `location` contains a structure like:

```
{
  key: 'ac3df4', // does not populate with a HashHistory!
  pathname: '/somepage',
  search: '?someurlparam=valuestring1&anotherurlparam=valuestring2',
  hash: '#about',
  state: {
    [userDefined]: true
  }
}
```

*Source: docs*

So you can compare the `pathname` with the current page (`props.location.pathname !== "/"`)

If your footer is in a different component, you can also pass the location property into the `Footer` (via `Layout` if needed) component and apply the same approach.